# CCXT Binance Future Order

Tags: python, binance, ccxt

I don't know Python very well and I'm trying to make a bot for Binance Futures with Python. And I encounter this error:

```
client.futures_create_order()(
TypeError: futures_create_order() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Here is my code:

```py
import ccxt

from binance.client import Client

client = Client("api key", "api secret")

client.futures_create_order()(
        symbol='BTCUSDT',
        side='BUY',
        type="MARKET",
        positionSide='SHORT',
        quantity=0.001,
        leverage=21
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error. Remove the empty parenthesis in `futures_create_order()`.

```
client.futures_create_order(
    symbol='BTCUSDT',
    side='BUY',
    type="MARKET",
    positionSide='SHORT',
    quantity=0.001,
    leverage=21)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but when i remove the paranthesis in "futures_create_order" i get error again.